# How to activate autocomplete option of tomtom in my html code?

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, tomtom

I have the following simple code for using tomtom which works:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class='use-all-space'>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge' />
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Maps SDK for Web - Search with autocomplete</title>

    <meta name='viewport'
        content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    href='https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/5.x/5.58.0/maps/maps.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    href='../assets/ui-library/index.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    href='https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/plugins/SearchBox/2.24.0//SearchBox.css' />

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    href='https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/plugins/SearchBox/2.24.2/SearchBox.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    href='https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/5.x/5.59.1/maps/css-styles/traffic-incidents.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    href='https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/5.x/5.59.1/maps/css-styles/routing.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    href='https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/5.x/5.59.1/maps/css-styles/poi.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <script
        src="https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/5.x/5.41.0/maps/maps-web.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/plugins/SearchBox/2.24.2/SearchBox-web.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/5.x/5.59.1/services/services-web.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src='https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/plugins/SearchBox/2.24.0//SearchBox-web.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
        src='../assets/js/search-markers/search-marker.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
        src='../assets/js/search/search-results-parser.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
        src='../assets/js/search-markers/search-markers-manager.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/info-hint.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/mobile-or-tablet.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
        src='../assets/js/search/results-manager.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/search/side-panel.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/search/dom-helpers.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/formatters.js'></script>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="myFunction()">
<input id="myId" type="text"></input>
<input id="myid2" type="submit"></input>
</form>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
         var query1 = document.getElementById("myId").value;

        tt.setProductInfo('My Application', '1.0');
        
        function callbackFn(result) {

            alert(result.results[0].position.lat);
        };

        tt.services.fuzzySearch({
            key : 'MyKey',
            query : query1
        }).go().then(callbackFn);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I would like to add the `typeahead` option to it. But I don't know how to do it. I have already seen some examples for the autocomplete option, like the one [here](https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-web-js/functional-examples#examples,code,search-with-autocomplete.html), but they are very very sophisticated codes (I even tried it, but I couldn't get it to run). I don't need to add any map to my code at all. I just have an input field that I would like to have an autocomplete option there, so that, the suggestions for the name of the place are shown to the user. Is there any straightforward way to do it?

I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>The form autocomplete attribute</h1>

    <p>Fill in and submit the form, then reload the page, start to fill in the form again - and see how autocomplete works.</p>
    <p>Then, try to set autocomplete to "off".</p>

    <form action="/action_page.php" method="get" autocomplete="on">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><be>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><be>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <p><b>Note:</b> The autocomplete attribute of the form element is not supported in     Opera 12 and earlier versions.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I actually, need to activate the autocomplete option of the tomtom web sdk in some way.